After ND during installation of Ubuntu 22.04 getting froze
I am trying for the last 3 days to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell Latitude 7390 with specs 16th ram 256 SSD core i5 8th generation. After installation it freezes ND never get back. I have to force shut down again again again. I am not able to do anything because it froze even before login

What does ND stand for?

Last two letters of "and".

This question is similar to: What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
